# What is meant by obj[''] in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, associative-array

Toward the bottom of [this javascript file](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1044242), there is a line

```
return map[""];
```

where `map` is an associative array of objects with parent/child relationships. After calling `map[""]` the returned structure is a transformation into a hierarchical array. What is really going on under the hood here and where is this syntax documented? (It's hard searching for such empty strings on the net.)

Comment: Ah, indeed, the root node has no name (an empty string), and it is this root object that is being returned. Thanks!

Comment: `->` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just reads the empty string property of `map`, just like how this:

```
map["a"]
```

is the same as

```
map.a
```

However, you can't just do

```
map.
```

so that's why they do

```
map[""]
```

This is generated by the function `find` which ends when the strings become empty, which is why the final element will be found in `map[""]`.